# Basic question about Bony decompositions - summation indices

Tags: combinatorics, harmonic-analysis, besov-space

I'm trying to understand some sort of inequality in a larger calculation. I believe my only issue  is in counting correctly, so I've also tagged combinatorics. Suppose I have a function $f$. Let $\triangle_q$, $q\ge -1$ be the Littlewood-Paley projection to frequencies $\sim q$, and $S_q=\sum_{-1\le j\le q-1} \triangle_j$ to be the projection to frequencies $\lesssim q$.

By this, I mean that for $q\ge 0$, $\triangle_q f$ has Fourier support on an annulus $A[2^{q-1},2^{q+1}]$, and $S_qf $ has Fourier support on a ball of radius $2^{q}$. Its also arranged that $\triangle_q$ and $S_q$ are Fourier multipliers (and so commute). With the standard set-up, we have for example (in a suitable sense)
\begin{align}
\sum_{q\ge -1} \triangle_q &= \operatorname{Id},\\
\triangle_q \triangle_j  &= 0\text{ if }|q-j|\ge 2, \\ S_{q-1}\triangle_q  &= 0, \text{ and}\\
S_{q+1}\triangle_q&=\triangle_q
\end{align}
Also define $\tilde{\triangle}_q := \triangle_{q-1} +  \triangle_q +  \triangle_{q+1}.  $I think I've said enough for my problem, for more details you can consult [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Littlewood-PaleyDecomposition.html), [Tao's notes](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/254a.1.01w/notes2.ps), or the book by Bahouri, Chemin and Danchin "Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear PDEs".

Now I have two functions, lets say $f,g$ and I've come across the following sum-
$$ \sum_{q\ge 1} \triangle_q f\tilde\triangle_q g$$
and I have the following bound,
$$ \|\triangle_q f\tilde\triangle_q g\|_{L^2} \le Ch_q$$

Why is it that
$$\triangle_j \sum_{q\ge 1} \triangle_q f\tilde\triangle_q g \overset{\Huge ?}\le C\sum_{\color{red}{q>j-4}} C h_q $$
My back-of-the-envelope is as follows. The Fourier support of $\triangle_q f \tilde \triangle_q g$ should be the sum of the two annuli. Since they can destructively and constructively interfere and everything in between, the Fourier support is now a ball of radius $2q+3$. For this ball to intersect the annulus $A[2^{j-1},2^{j+1}]$, we need $2q+3> j-1$. This leads do
$$ 2q > j-4$$
Did I understand something wrongly?

Comment: I can provide plenty more details, if needed (just ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just doesn't add like that :)

we have the following explicit calculations

\begin{align} \DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{supp}
&x\in\supp \triangle_qf \implies   &c 2^q& \le |x| \le C 2^q,  
\\&x\in\supp \tilde \triangle_qg\implies  &\frac{c}2 2^{q-1} &\le |x| \le 2C 2^{q}, 
\\&x\in\supp \triangle f \tilde \triangle_qg\implies  &  &\quad\,|x| \le (2C+C) 2^{q}=3C2^q, 
\end{align}
I believe $c$ is taken to be a number in $(0.5,1)$ and $C$ a number  in $(2,4)$. In practice one normally fixes  $c=3/4, C=8/3$, so
$$ 3C2^q = 82^q = 2^{q+3}. $$
So $\triangle_j$ of the product is zero if $j-1>q+3$. This means we should sum over (as a possible overestimation) $q$ such that $j-1\le q+3$ (typo in question).

For the range of $C$ I indicated above one gets $3C2^q \in (6\cdot 2^q,\frac{15}2\cdot 2^q)=(0.75\cdot 2^{q+3}, 1.5 2^{q+3})$.

(Thanks Zhu Ning for setting me straight.)